# `rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo` is no longer working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

This used to work alright. Now I am getting this error:

```
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
** Invoke paperclip:refresh (first_time)
** Invoke paperclip:refresh:metadata (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute paperclip:refresh:metadata
rake aborted!
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/app/models/media.rb:23:in `touch_organization'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2551:in `save_without_validation!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1019:in `save_without_dirty!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:87:in `save_without_transactions!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:37:in `touch'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `method_missing'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/app/models/gallery.rb:16:in `touch_media'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2551:in `save_without_validation!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1019:in `save_without_dirty!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:87:in `save_without_transactions!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:37:in `touch'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `method_missing'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1348:in `belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_gallery'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:251:in `create_or_update'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2534:in `save_without_validation'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1009:in `save_without_dirty'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_without_transactions'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:59
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:26:in `for_all_attachments'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:24:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:24:in `for_all_attachments'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:22:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:22:in `for_all_attachments'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/lib/tasks/paperclip_tasks.rake:54
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => paperclip:refresh => paperclip:refresh:metadata
```

Can anyone make heads or tails of what is happening here and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo` (notice the uppercase P)?

Comment: Something is up at `app/models/media.rb:23`.
Can you post the paperclip related code here?

Comment: Mikker, I think I found a piece of corrupted data. Ex. a few pieces that lost their connection to a join model. They are then touched by `touch_organization` in an after_save method and crash the process.